# In-app billing v3 test purchase not working across devices

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have setup three Managed items in my developer account for in-app purchases, and my app is currently in the Beta channel on the Play Store.

I want to test the in-app purchase across two devices that use the same Google account -- but am finding that only the device that makes the purchase is correctly finding the purchase.  The second device, using the same Google account, does not find the purchase.

**Should test account billing work across any device that uses the same Google account?**

I'm using the Billing helper libraries and here's my code at start-up to check for purchases:

ActivityStartUp.java

```
@Override
public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
{
    if (!result.isSuccess()) 
    {
        LOGD(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
        startApplication();
    } 
    else 
    {             
        LOGD(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");

        // Query In-App billing for purchases
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(new QueryInventoryFinishedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) 
            {
                if (inv.hasPurchase(Globals.ITEM1_SKU) || 
                    inv.hasPurchase(Globals.ITEM2_SKU) ||
                    inv.hasPurchase(Globals.ITEM3_SKU))
                {
                    // Store PRO purchase state
                    AccountUtils.setProVersion(ActivityStartUp.this, true);

                    LOGD(TAG, "Ad-free.  User has purchased the Upgrade :)");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Store PRO purchase state
                    AccountUtils.setProVersion(ActivityStartUp.this, false);

                    LOGD(TAG, "Using the free version, with Ads");
                }

                // Start the application
                startApplication();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be that Google Play is caching the response on the second device. It seems to take some hours or maybe even days for update sometimes.

Comment: Same problem here 3 years later.