# SKU bought with IAP doesn't show up on as purchased on a second device owned by the same user

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I get this complaint every so often that a user buys my premium features with IAP and that it works fine on the device they bought but their other device won't get the features, I ask them to reboot the other device and that usually fixes it. So the other day I tried to see if I could do something about this so I purchased on one of my devices (test account) and then I went to the other, killed my app to make sure it was starting from zero, and then stepped the code. The query of purchases was actually returning no purchases. It did not tell me about purchases until I tried to buy premium from that device. Trying to buy premium from that device didn't create a dialog or anything, it just returned as if nothing had happened but after that the device had that purchase on its inventory.

Here are the methods I have, I am using the IABHelper from Google's example and I think I updated it just a month ago.

```
public void createIABHelper(final Context ac) {
        mHelper = new IabHelper(ac, myid);
        try {
            mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                        // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                        Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);

                    } else {
                        iabSetup = true;
                        //queryIAB(ac);
                        queryIABPurchases(ac);

                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            final String desc = "Error starting IABHelper";
            Log.w(TAG, desc, e);

        }

    }


public void queryIAB(final Context ctx) {

        List<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        additionalSkuList.add(Constants.PREMIUM_UPGRADE);

        IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener
                mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    // handle error
                    return;
                } else {
                    Purchase p = inventory.getPurchase(Constants.PREMIUM_UPGRADE);
                    if (p != null) {

                        setHasPremiumPref(p.getPurchaseState() == 0);
                    } else {
                        setHasPremiumPref(false);
                    }
                }
                // inventory.hasDetails(PREMIUM_UPGRADE);


                // update the UI
            }
        };
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList,
                mQueryFinishedListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void purchaseIAB(final Activity ac) {
        if (iabSetup) {
            try {


                final String finalPayload = ....;
                IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
                        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
                    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
                        if (result.isFailure()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
                            return;
                        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(Constants.PREMIUM_UPGRADE)) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Purchased " + purchase.getPurchaseState());
                            if (purchase.getDeveloperPayload().equals(finalPayload) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == 0) {

                                setHasPremiumPref(true);
                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Something went wrong verifying purchase.");

                                setHasPremiumPref(false);

                            }
                        }

                    }
                };

                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(ac, Constants.PREMIUM_UPGRADE, 10001,
                        mPurchaseFinishedListener, finalPayload);
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                final String msg = "Error starting in-app purchase";
                Log.w(TAG, msg, ex);

            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "IAB not setup.");
        }
    }

public void queryIABPurchases(Context ctx) {
        if (iabSetup) {
            IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener
                    = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
                public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                                     Inventory inventory) {

                    if (result.isFailure()) {
                        // handle error here
                    } else {
                        // does the user have the premium upgrade?
                        Purchase p = inventory.getPurchase(Constants.PREMIUM_UPGRADE);
                        if (p != null) {

                            setHasPremiumPref(p.getPurchaseState() == 0);
                        } else {
                            setHasPremiumPref(false);
                        }

                        // update UI accordingly
                    }

                }
            };
            List<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
            additionalSkuList.add(Constants.PREMIUM_UPGRADE);
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, additionalSkuList, mGotInventoryListener);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "IAB not setup.");


        }

    }
```

Anyways, basically I use `queryIABPurchases` but `p` is always null on that second device. Is this an issue with test accounts or maybe something to do with time, do I maybe need to wait a few hours before testing on the second device?

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue.  Possible duplicate to the question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591155/in-app-billing-v3-test-purchase-not-working-across-devices  One thing -- make sure you're not "consuming" the purchase somewhere in your code.

Comment: You are right, it does sound like a duplicate. I voted for it hoping someone will help. I am not consuming. I should point out I've had this same IAP setup since around April and I've had people report the issue with other devices since around then but it is always fixed with a tablet/phone reboot.